# c# AD computer account DN

Tags: c#

How i can get AD computer account DN in c# using principal

```
public string GetcomputerExtededProperty(string fieldName)
    {
        try
        {
            ComputerPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = GetComputer();
            return GetProperty((DirectoryEntry)oGroupPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject(), fieldName);

        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Your code looks fine to me, (albeit a bit odd way to retrieve the property (and you are not properly disposing your objects)). Are you getting some kind of error? Please provide more details in your question or it will likely be closed for being "not a real question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can use the `FindByIdentity` method and `DistinguishedName` property of the [`ComputerPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.computerprincipal.aspx) class (in  `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace and assembly):

```
PrincipalContext oCtx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
ComputerPrincipal oPrincipal = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oCtx, computerName);
string dn = oPrincipal.DistinguishedName;
```

Comment: The name computername does not exist in the current context

Comment: As advice i had tried below and receive error (Not all code paths return a value)  public bool Getcomputerou(string computerName, string domain)
    {
        
            PrincipalContext oCtx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            ComputerPrincipal oPrincipal = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oCtx, computerName);
             string dn = oPrincipal.DistinguishedName;
        
    }

Comment: Your function should return the value. Add this line as the last  statement: `return dn;`.